# How to get the unique viewers count of a document?

Tags: search-results, pnp-powershell, pnp, sharepoint-search

I see in SharePoint per document the viewers count. I would like to generate a csv report for all my documents in a specific site/library. I try this PowerShell command, but the the properties "ViewsLifetime, ViewsLifetimeUniqueUsers" are empty in my results.

```
Submit-PnPSearchQuery -Query "* Path:https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/someSpecificSite" -All -TrimDuplicates $False -SelectProperties ViewsLifetime, ViewsLifetimeUniqueUsers, Path
```

[image]

When I try the rest api url I see the properties has a value

```
https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/someSpecificSite/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/someSpecificSite'&selectproperties='Title,Path,ViewsLifetime,ViewsLifetimeUniqueUsers'
```

[image]

Here is an example of the viewers count of a specific document

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by my self as follow:

```
$SiteUrl = "https://myCompant.sharepoint.com/teams/someSite"
$SearchQuery = "Path: https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/teams/someSite/someLibrary"
$CSVFile = "C:\Temp\searchResults.csv"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Interactive
 
#Execute Search
$SearchResults = Submit-PnPSearchQuery -Query $SearchQuery -All -TrimDuplicates $False -SelectProperties Path, ViewsLifetime,ViewsLifetimeUniqueUsers
```